# Detecting if a key is down inside onCreate()

Tags: android

I have android barcode scanner with physical keyboard. Is possible on app startup inside onCreate() method detect if some key is pressed and hold down? The idea is that if app is starting and key `X` is down then load another configuration. Like safe mode for firefox when shift key is pressed when firefox is starting.

Edit.
Use case:

- App is starting ( onCreate ).
- get default activity from settings. Ex myAct="actA.java"
- if key 1 is down then myAct="defaultActivity.java"
- startActivityForResult(myAct)

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? It's just the normal key press detection. (Then if it doesn't work, you post a question) :-)

Comment: @Blundell, can you suggest function/method to try? onKeyDown triggers after onCreate...

Comment: Can you explain your use case/requirement?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11713669/413127

Comment: Which view should be used then?

Comment: This might help you a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186555/bluetooth-device-button-press-should-trigger-onclick-listener-in-the-app

Comment: Use your root view, i.e. the main LinearLayout / FrameLayout / CoordinatorLayout that makes up your whole view.  But then I guess you are talking about a key press not a touch event

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but perhaps some sort of splash screen as your first activity, not only will this give the user a chance to press a key (you have no guarantee of the context if you try to detect it before your app starts), but in Activity you can simply override onKeyDown. eg.

- SplashActivityLoads and displays for 5 seconds
- Using override fun onKeyDown(); detect which key has been pressed and store in a local variable
- After you SplashActivity 5 seconds (or whatever) is up, use your stored variable to decide which Activity to launch, if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_X) actA.java else defaultActivity.java